# Running the same test for different datasets in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, data-driven-tests

I want to run a simple test scenario in Cypress where user logs in by entering the username and password and clicks on the submit button. I want to test this with different username and password combination. It is very easy in cucumber-java. You can write a scenario outline and add those different data sets (username and password combination).

Can any one show me how it can be achieved in cypress?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to have one test, that would use different data each run, just invoke `it()` in a loop.

Example from the Cypress Docs on how to [**Dynamically Generate Tests**](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Dynamically-Generate-Tests):

```js
describe('if your app uses jQuery', () => {
  ['mouseover', 'mouseout', 'mouseenter', 'mouseleave'].forEach((event) => {
    it('triggers event: ' + event, () => {
      // if your app uses jQuery, then we can trigger a jQuery
      // event that causes the event callback to fire
      cy
        .get('#with-jquery').invoke('trigger', event)
        .get('#messages').should('contain', 'the event ' + event + 'was fired')
    })
  })
})
```